# clear gnu screen window name

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using screen with a hardstatus listing my open windows, I usually have a few named (mail, im, top, etc.) and a few with blank name.
Some program changes the current window name, for my named window that's not a problem: Ctrl+a, A: allow me to change back the name. but the same command does not want an empty string as the name and keep the current name in that case.

So, how can I set an empty name to screen window? A single space does not count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the screen colon command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> and enter the command `title ""`.